# ADFS 2016 Not Returning XML Unless Localhost

Tags: windows-server-2016, adfs

I have recently set up an ADFS 2016 server and restored an export from a previous ADFS 2.0 on Windows 2008 R2. Passed the new configuration through [MS' analyzer](https://adfshelp.microsoft.com/DiagnosticsAnalyzer/Analyze) with no issues (except for using a wildcard cert which seems to confuse it).

Using Chrome on the ADFS server, when I surf to the service: (fqdn = adfs.corp.mydomain.com = federation service name)

1. http://fqdn --> default IIS page
2. https://fqdn --> cannot be reached
3. http://localhost/adfs/fs/federationserverservice.asmx --> 503
4. https://localhost/adfs/fs/federationserverservice.asmx --> XML
5. http://fqdn/adfs/fs/federationserverservice.asmx    --> 503
6. https://fqdn/adfs/fs/federationserverservice.asmx    --> cannot be reached

So, according to the first and fourth responses, I can viably reach the service and it responds with XML. But, I'm not sure why I can't get the response when using the full domain name and path in the last URL? How do I diagnose this?

Answer (score 1):

What about the normal metadata endpoint:

https://myserver.domain.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml

ADFS only answers to https and in 2016 does not use IIS.